# jvectormap cannot add marker from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

I have a jvectormap that I am trying to get json data to create the markers. I am getting a console error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

I have been at this for a while. I Can't seem to get one that error to go away and get the makers on the map. Any Help Appreciated

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

var map = $("#map");
map.vectorMap({
    map: 'us_lcc_en',
    zoomMin: '0',
    backgroundColor: '#2d3641',
    focusOn: {
        x: 1,
        y: 1,
        scale: 1
    },
    markerStyle: {
        initial: {
            fill: '#ff4e50',
            stroke: '#000',
            "stroke-width": 2,
            "stroke-opacity": 0.3,
        }
    },
    regionStyle: {
        initial: {
            fill: '#dfdfdf',
            "fill-opacity": 1,
            stroke: 'none',
            "stroke-width": 0,
            "stroke-opacity": 1
        },
        hover: {
            "fill-opacity": 0.8
        },
        selected: {
            fill: 'yellow'
        },
        selectedHover: {}
    }
});

$.post( "data.json.php?a=vector_map_orders", function( data ) {
    var map = $('#map').vectorMap('get', 'map');
    $.each(data.result, function(i, item) {
        map.addMarker(markerIndex, {latLng: [item.lat, item.long], name: item.city, style: {r:5.413333333}});
    });
}, "json");
```

});

Comment: I think @bjornd tries to tell you, that markers doesn't appear because you are not referencing them in your map.vectormap. I believe, the best approach for you would be to reference markers as markers: myArray, and create this array inside your  $.post call. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dqxccd7h/1/